# ListView Visible property

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a search results page where the list views visible property is always `false` on the first page load even though I set the value to `true` as seen below. It seems line is being ignored? Is there a reason why this property cannot be set on the first load?

[image]

**EDIT:** Page load Event

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   if (!IsPostBack)
   {
      if (Request.QueryString["query"] != null)
      {
         _searchTerm = Request.QueryString["query"].ToString();
         GetSearchResults();
         txtSearchBox.Text = _searchTerm;
       }
    }
 }
```

ListView Markup

```
<asp:PlaceHolder runat="server" ID="SearchResults" Visible="false">
 ...
<asp:ListView id="lvSearch" runat="server">
    <LayoutTemplate>
        <ul id="SearchResultsList">
            <asp:PlaceHolder runat="server" ID="itemPlaceholder"></asp:PlaceHolder>
        </ul> 
    </LayoutTemplate>
    <ItemTemplate>
        <li class="searchResult">
            <h2><%#DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Title")%></h2>
            <p><%#DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "HighlightedPreview")%></p>
            <a href="<%#DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "URL")%>"><%#DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "URL")%></a>
        </li>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:ListView>
<div runat="server" id="NoResults" visible="false">
    <p>The current search has returned no results. Please enter another search term in the box above.</p>
</div>
</asp:PlaceHolder>
```

Comment: This information is not enough to answer you. And the line which you have written here is not in form load. Please, post the entire code part.

Comment: I think the condition is not satisfying either the PostBack one or the one nested in it. And what type of control is NoResults? Check that it is not acting as a container for ListView.

Comment: From the image you can see the line is being hit as I have moved on to the next one, No Results is simply a div run at server.

Comment: Try to make ListView visible by default using its property window. And check that it is not in the DIV-NoResults.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check that it is not in the DIV-NoResults or some other container that is going invisible.

Comment: Ah, Yes the ListView is contained within a placeholder which is set to Visible false. Seems the containers visible value overrides all children

Comment: Ya that's true. The container is like a box which contains its component or even other small boxes. If you remove that box, all the things inside it will be removed.